# Could SynchronizationContext be used not in WinForms/WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization, ynchronizationontext

I'm writing a component that would be used in WinForms or WPF applications also could be used in Windows services or Unit tests. Is there a way to use SynchronizationContext component in non UI apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any (host) application can make its own `SynchronizationContext` class and call [`SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.setsynchronizationcontext.aspx).

Alternatively, you could make a no-op `SynchronizationContext` in your library, then use it whenever `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null`.

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882417/looking-for-an-example-of-a-custom-synchronizationcontext) talks about writing a custom SynchronizationContext.

Comment: Of how "application can make its own SynchronizationContext", i.e. application wihtout UI loop, like Windows service.

Comment: If you need the callbacks to execute on a single thread, you'll need to make a thread-safe queue of pending callbacks and an infinite loop on the callback thread that executes the first callback on the queue.